# How to sort default dict with list values in python

Tags: python, list, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict with list as

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'SOL200122': ['125', '135', '145', '170', '120', '130', '140', '150', '160']}
```

I want it to be sorted like

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'SOL200122': ['120', '125', '130', '135', '140', '145', '150', '160', '170']}
```

Have tried

```
sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda k_v: (k_v[1][2]), reverse=True)
```

But not working

Comment: `myDict['SOL200122'].sort()`? `for l in myDict.values(): l.sort()`…?

Comment: I have not only one key, i have multiple keys

Comment: But you don't want to sort the dict right? You want to sort ***its values***?

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.sort` with `key=int` (thanks @Metapod, @deceze et al):

```
for v in d.values():
    v.sort(key=int)
```

If you want a one-liner (which makes no sense in this case because for-loop is very nice), a monstrosity like this one could be one I guess:

```
dict(zip(d.keys(), map(lambda x: sorted(x, key=int), d.values())))
```

Output:

```
{'SOL200122': ['120', '125', '130', '135', '140', '145', '150', '160', '170']}
```

Comment: It works if all the values have the same number of digits. ```a = ["170", "120", "40"];
a.sort(); >> ['120', '170', '40']``` // ```a = ["170", "120", "040"]; a.sort(); >> ['040', '120', '170']```

Comment: Is there any inbuilt function rather than sorting manually

Comment: The characters will be differant , wont be same always.

Comment: You can maybe turn the strings into integers if possible.

Comment: Convert list elements to `int`.

Comment: yeah please help on that case.. @Metapod

Comment: `v.sort(key=int)`…!

Comment: After adding key=int its working.. Is there any oneliner or built in function for more efficiency than for loop

Comment: @Kowsi You want to repeat the same operation on multiple elements, you *will* need a loop in some way or another. This is the most straight forward way, no need to dress it up as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for v in d.values():
    v.sort(key=int)
```

output:

```
{'SOL200122': ['120', '125', '130', '135', '140', '145', '150', '160', '170']}
```

Comment: This is working, any one liner like sort(mydict) instead of for loop.